# send a PNG file with TCP connection

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to send a png image (screenshot) from a server to a client.

I decode it and send the decoded string to the client and the client use it to save the image in his computer.

But the image i get from the client isn't perfect, at all...

Client

```
while "finish" not in data:
        data += receive(data_len)
    data = data[:-7]

fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
fh.write(data.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```

SERVER

```
ImageGrab.grab().save("screen_capture.png", "PNG")
            #Convert the image to a string that it will be able to be send to the client
            with open("screen_capture.png", "rb") as imageFile:
                Image_Str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
            fh = open("text", "wb")
            fh.write(Image_Str)
            fh.close
            fh = open("text", "rb")
            str1 = fh.read(150)
            client_socket.send("150~" + str1)
            while str1:
                str1 = fh.read(150)
                client_socket.send(str1)
            client_socket.send("6finish")
```

I tried to check if the strings are the same- and it seems like they are..
when i try to decode the string back to an image in the server- it works...

Comment: Might the string "finish" appear in the base64 encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `client_socket.sendall(strl)` instead of `send`.

When sending data using `send` the OS will tell you how much has been accepted to be sent over the network but it may be less than the full length of the string.

`sendall` is a python method for sockets that does the required looping for you.

Comment: Thank!!! working!! this is what i did to receive:                                     while True:
        try:
            my_socket.settimeout(0.5)
            data += my_socket.recv(150)
        except socket.error:
            break